# Select top 3 groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I use SQL Server 2008

I have the following table `T1`

```
Std_Name | Grade
-------------
ALI      | 60
San      | 55
Saqo     | 55
SARA     | 50
JOER     | 50
MANDA    | 50
AEROP    | 25
NOAM     | 24
```

How can I got the students with the top **3** highest grades?

The result should be like:

```
RNK# - Std_Name | Grade
-----------------
1-    ALI   | 60
2-    San   | 55
2-    Saqo  | 55
3-    SARA  | 50
3-    JOER  | 50
3-    MANDA | 50
```

without using  OLAP functions like RnK FUNCTION

DBRM is SQL SERVER
I need rank number as I write down

Comment: Why would you even think about OLAP?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the RANK function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the rows where the count of distinct grades of equal or higher value is three or less.

```
Select * from T1 a
where (select count(distinct grade)
       from t1
       where grade >= a.Grade) <= 3
```

with rank in output results

```
Select (select count(distinct grade)
        from t1
        where grade >= a.Grade) rank,
     Std_Name, Grade
from T1 a
where (select count(distinct grade)
       from t1
       where grade >= a.Grade) <= 3
```

Comment: I need a rank number before the std_name

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT    *,
      @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      t1, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  grade desc limit 0,3 ;
```

Comment: I need a rank number before the std_name

Comment: @jonasvermeulen - Jack isn't the OP. This may or may not work for the OP as it seems to be using non standard MySQL functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
select std_name, grade from T1 where grade in
    (select top 3 grade from T1 order by grade desc)
order by grade desc
```

Comment: I need a rank number  before  the std_name

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the *distinct* top scores first, take the top 3 of *those*, then go from there:

```
select Std_Name, Grade
from t1
where grade in (
    select top 3 distinct grade
    from t1
    order by grade desc
)
```

You haven't told us your RDBMS, so `top 3` (SQLServer) may become `limit 3` (mysql) etc.

Comment: It is not true , try with data : 60 60 60 60 55 and the select top 3 :) 
it will return only  60 60 60 .. the required is to be distinct 3

Comment: @MargoStefin Ahhhgggh! I put `distinct` in the commentary, but left it out of the query! It's in now. As for the rank, I'm not coding anything until you tag your question with the database you are using. The syntax is too varied for one answer

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the OLAP `RnK` function is.  But SQL Server supports the ANSI standard window function `dense_rank()` that does exactly what you want.  This would be used as:

```
select [RNK#], Std_Name, Grade
from (select t1.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by grade desc) as [RNK#]
      from t1
     ) t1
where [RNK#] <= 3;
```

Okay, this doesn't put the hyphen after the ranking (which is easily done using character manipulation), but I don't see why that is desirable.

Comment: please do not use dense_rank()  or Rank()  or any OLAP FUNCTION please please !!!!

Comment: @MargoStefin . . . Can you explain why you don't want to use the ANSI standard function specifically designed to do what you are asking for?

Comment: simple sql function like count , group , average ...etc